# if statement has no comparison operator only an equal, what does it mean?

Tags: php

I have some code from a previous programmer and I'm a little confused to what it means.
The if statement is:

```
    if( !$this->report = $this->get_report()){
... do something }
```

I'm used to seeing the if statement with some "truthy" condition or a comparison operator.

Is this saying if $this->report is false or doesn't exist then make it = $this_.get_report()?

Comment: No. `$a = $b` is an expression whose value is `$b`. Read your code as `!($a = $b)`: it assigns `$this->get_report()` to `$this->report` and, if `$this->get_report()` is falsy (due to the `!`), it gets into the conditional block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( !$this->report = $this->get_report())
```

This line is doing two things:

1. assigning the value of `$this->get_report()` to `$this->report`
2. validating whether the value [loosely compares](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to `false`

Only if it does compare (loosely to `false`), it runs the block `do something`

---

Example of another loose comparison:

```
<?php
if(!$foo = null) {
    // going to process this block
}
```

1. `$foo` is assigned a `null` value
2. `null` loosely compares to `false` in PHP

   1. `null == false` loose comparison
   2. `null !== false` strict comparison
3. `!false` results in `true`, so the block gets executed